# How to build a Open domain question answering model(ODQA/KBQA) using Deeppavlov of Huggingface

Tags: huggingface-transformers, nlp-question-answering, deeppavlov

How to build a Open domain question answering(ODQA/KBQA) model using Deeppavlov of Huggingface

I want to build a custom model for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this tutorial for building a custom ODQA model https://colab.research.google.com/github/deepmipt/dp_notebooks/blob/master/DP_ODQA.ipynb

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this is quite helpful. But I want to train this model using my own data. Can you please tell how to create the complete dataset??    @user15904302